# How to query a postgresql table twice in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cartodb

I have two tables.

**af_fibrephase** is a list of fibre optic network projects in Africa and consists of the key fields:

- the_geom <- map of the fibre network
- operator_id <- a unique id for the network operator
- owner_id <- a unique id for the network owner

**af_organisation** is a table that provides more detailed information about the organisations referenced in af_fibrephase.  I have used a single table for both operator and owner organisations because they are sometimes the same thing and sometimes not. Key fields for af_organisation are:

- organisation_id <- key reference field
- name <- organisation name
- web_url <- url of organisations
- etc

I would like to make a query which pulls up the project from af_fibrephase and populates the details about both the owner and the operator from the organisation table. Looking through examples, it seems like something like the following should work but it produces a join error.

```
SELECT af_fibrephase.* 
FROM af_fibrephase AS fibre
INNER JOIN af_organisation AS org1 on fibre.operator_id = org1.organisation_id
INNER JOIN af_organisation AS org2 on fibre.owner_id = org2.organisation_id
```

Actual tables can be found at [af_fibrephase](https://afterfibre.carto.com/tables/af_fibrephase/public/map) and [af_organisation](https://afterfibre.carto.com/tables/af_organisation/public/map) on https://carto.com

Comment: it produces an error because you are using the tablename after defining an alias..in `select`.

Comment: Instead of INNER JOIN, use LEFT JOIN on both. Then in your SELECT, reference the org1 and org2 columns you need.

Comment: Thank you both [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970497/shawn) and [Juergen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d).  Now I actually understand the difference between an inner and left join, and also that left and left outer joins are the same thing.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php <<< That is T-SQL, but this is pretty generic SQL, and the link puts the JOIN types into a graphical presentation that is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See above comment. Use LEFT OUTER JOIN and alias needed fields from af_organisation.

```
SELECT fibre.*
    , org1.name AS operator_name
    , org1.web_url AS operator_web_url
    , org1.<etc> AS operator_<etc>
    , org2.name AS owner_name
    , org2.web_url AS owner_web_url
    , org2.<etc> AS owner_<etc>
FROM af_fibrephase AS fibre
LEFT OUTER JOIN af_organisation org1 on fibre.operator_id = org1.organisation_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN af_organisation org2 on fibre.owner_id = org2.organisation_id
```

Comment: NOTE: If your fibrephase doesn't have an owner or an operator, a NULL will show up in the place of those. If you want to eliminate those that don't have both an owner and an operator, you can go back to the INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fibre.*, 
       org1.name as org1_name,
       org2.name as org2_name
FROM af_fibrephase AS fibre
LEFT JOIN af_organisation AS org1 on fibre.operator_id = org1.organisation_id
LEFT JOIN af_organisation AS org2 on fibre.owner_id = org2.organisation_id
```